# How to convert two programs into a multithreaded process

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, unix

I have these two programs:

```
/* system.c*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define OUTPUTNAME "write.out"
main()
{
    long i;
    int fd;

    if ((fd=open(OUTPUTNAME,O_WRONLY|O_CREAT,0644)) <  0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Can't open %s.  Bye.\n",OUTPUTNAME);
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i=0; i<50000; i++)  { /* write 50,000 Ys with write */
        if (write(fd,"Y",1) < 1) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Can't write. Bye\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    close(fd);
    exit(0);
}
```

And..

```
/* library.c*/
#include <stdio.h>
#define OUTPUTNAME "fprint.out"
main()
{
    long i;
    FILE *fp;

    if ((fp=fopen(OUTPUTNAME,"w")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Can't open %s.  Bye.\n",OUTPUTNAME);
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i=0; i<400000; i++) {  /* write 400,000 Xs with fprintf */
        if (fprintf(fp,"X") < 1) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Can't write. Bye\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    exit(0);
}
```

I want to convert them into a multithreaded process such that the process starts both the treads simultaneously. How do I do that? I am fairly new to this.

Comment: Just as an alternative, is there something wrong with simply running the programs simultaneously in their own processes?

Answer (score 0):

Use `pthread` to create two threads, then run them as follows,

```
gcc myProgram.o -o myProgram -lpthread
```

For more information check this [article](http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/threads/threads.c.php).

Comment: I read the article, and I understood how to create a thread and all. But, I still don't understand how to make these two programs as two thread in a process and run them in parallel. :O

Comment: Create `pthread` for both program like above mentioned and run them in individual terminals. They will run in parallel.

Comment: Does this mean that they are in one process?

Comment: Skynet, I want to create two threads in the same program and then run the at the same time. I don't understand how to do that.

Comment: @MarthaPears check article I think answer of your question lies clearly in there, make two pthreads and keep each program into each of them. then how to call is also mentioned in artilcle.